# design a regular expression to print out a list of words that start and end with the same 3 letters unix

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

design a regular expression to print out a list of words that start and end with the same 3 letters. For example: **mic**rocos**mic**, **ent**rancem**ent** etc. i need it in unix.

Comment: What did you already try? SO is not meant to ask people to create your code...

Comment: but in most cases people just give solutions and don't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your first post .... you can use `grep` (GNU grep 2.16)

```
grep -E "^(.{3}).*\1$" file.txt
```

input `file.txt`

```
microcosmic
hello
entrancement
world
```

you get,

```
microcosmic
entrancement
```

**explanation**

- ^     : beginning of line
- (...) : backreference mark
- .{3}  : first three letter
- .*    : whatever
- \1    : backreference
- $     : ending of line

**EDIT**

if, you look for each word that start and end with the same 3 letters in a text

```
 echo "microcosmic gshgshi entrancement hello world" | 
 grep -E -o "\b(.{3})\S*\1\b"
```

you get,

```
microcosmic
entrancement
```

- \b        : a regular expression means "word boundary"
- \S        : It isn't blank space
- -o option : Print only the matched

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Words like to `abc` or `ababa` It don't works, in this case you can use `awk` without regular expressions

```
echo "microcosmic gshgshi entrancement hello world abc ababa" |  
awk 'length($0)<3{next;}
     substr($0,1,3) == substr($0,length($0)-2,3)' RS="[ \n\t]+"
```

you get,

```
microcosmic
entrancement
abc
ababa
```

Comment: what if you have several words in the same line?

Comment: `grep -E -o "\b(.{3})\S*\1\b" file.txt` only, in this case

Comment: what about '\b(.{3}).*\1' ?

Comment: i think that's what OP wanted

Comment: thanks I edited in post